# det of polynomial: singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working with  $1+x^2 +x^4$ on interval 
$[0,1]$ I evaluated the determinant of the matrix
**$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
x_{1}^{2} & x_{2}^{2} & x_{3}^{2} \\
x_{1}^{4} & x_{2}^{4} & x_{3}^{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$**
The determinant of the above matrix is
**$$ \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
x_{1}^{2} & x_{2}^{2} & x_{3}^{2} \\
x_{1}^{4} & x_{2}^{4} & x_{3}^{4} \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 0 &0& 1 \\ (x_1^2 -x_2^2)& (x_2^2 -x_3^2)& x_3^2\\(x_1^4 - x_2^4)& (x_2^4 -x_3^4) & x_3^4 
\end{vmatrix} $$**
$$\Delta =(x_1^2 -x_2^2)(x_2^4 -x_3^4)-(x_2^2 -x_3^2)(x_1^4 - x_2^4) $$
which reduces to $$(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)(x_3-x_1)(x_1+x_3)(x_2-x_3)(x_2+x_3)$$

since all the $ x_1,x_2 , x_3$ on interval [0,1] none of the factor above is zero so equation is not zero.
That means det matrix is not singular.

Is this approach correct ?
Thanks

Comment: The matrices you claim are equal are obviously **not** equal. The topmost leftmost element is $1$ in one of the matrices and $0$ in the other.

Comment: that's how my teacher did it. He subtracts columns from first vector to get second vector.

Comment: Either you're misunderstanding your teacher, or what he is teaching is not mathematics. Two matrices described in those ways **can never be the same matrix**. You can see plain as day how they differ.

Comment: so if I did not write equal sign between them, would process of subtracting the columns is allowed in order to get to det of a matrix ?

Comment: You're of course "allowed" to compute the determinant of a matrix in any way you want. You're also "allowed" to claim that two matrices are equal when they are not -- that just makes your claim false, but it's not as if there is a math police that will arrest you if you write down such false claims.

Comment: Typically in Linear Algebra, what you should do instead is use the $\sim$ symbol when showing the resulting matrix after performing a row operation. This is because the matrices are considered *row equivalent*. So for example, $$\pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1} \overset{{1\over2}R_1\to R_1}{\huge\sim} \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1}.$$

Comment: It is also true that your two non-equal matrices (which you falsely claim are equal) happen to have the same determinant. But it is not necessarily true that the determinant they share is nonzero. You seem to claim that just because your $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are all in the interval $[0,1]$ the factors you write down will be nonzero. But that is not so -- for example, if $x_1=x_2=x_3=1/2$ then three of your factors will be zero.

Comment: henning, I chose interval my self.  Mostly equally spaced. So they will not be equal to each other. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Your first matrix is also (the transpose of) a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), which gives a nicer reason for the factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Vandermonde determinant cancels if and only if two generating elements are equal. In this case, if two $x_k^2$ are equal.